# Shell Script SSH behaviours

Tags: shell, ssh

I started to code shell scripting for about 2 days

currently I have the following code

```
echo "Permission to Access to Remote Machine"
ssh $USERNAME@$HOSTNAME  "pg_dump -f /dbexport.sql -t tb1 -t tb2 -t tb3 dbname"
echo "Permission to Access to Remote Machine to transfer data file"
scp $USERNAME@$HOSTNAME:/dbexport.sql /export/bin/
echo "Permission to delete temporary file on remote machine"
ssh $USERNAME@$HOSTNAME  "rm /dbexport.sql"
echo "Creating Database..."
```

Now I have 2 questions

1- is there a good way to make this operation in a once? I have to do it 3 times currently... and I don't want to use expect neither other 3rd party script neither I want to use RSA keys to ssh authentication

2- is there a way to know if something has failed on that commands?

Thanks a Lot

Comment: You have a mismatched quotation mark on the first line.

Comment: Why don't you want to use RSA keys?  (I presume your reason applies equally to DSA keys.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remotely dump the database to a local file I'd dump it to stdout and redirect it locally, e.g.

```
ssh $USERNAME@$HOSTNAME "pg_dump -f /dev/stdout -t tb1 -t tb2 -t tb3 dbname" > /export/bin/dbexport.sql
```

The return code of the command line executed on the server is returned to you as the return code of the ssh call.  If ssh fails (e.g. connection issue) you get 255.  If all is okay you get 0.

Bash provides you the return code of the last executed command in the shell variable $?.  You can use it the following way:

```
ssh $USERNAME@$HOSTNAME "pg_dump -f /dev/stdout -t tb1 -t tb2 -t tb3 dbname" > /export/bin/dbexport.sql
err=$?
if [ $err -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Dump failed with error code ${err}!"
fi
```

Or if you are not interested in the exact value:

```
if ! ssh $USERNAME@$HOSTNAME "pg_dump -f /dev/stdout -t tb1 -t tb2 -t tb3 dbname" > /export/bin/dbexport.sql; then
  echo "Dump failed!"
fi
```

The `pg_dump` man page will probably give you the error codes for it. From the ssh man page:

```
EXIT STATUS
     ssh exits with the exit status of the remote command or with 255 if an
     error occurred.
```

Comment: That seems great!

could you provide me more info about the ssh return value?
it will return false if it fails for any reason... even a wrong password?

Comment: Added return value info to above answer.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, I can't think of a good way to combine the three commands into one  If they were all executing commands on the remote machine, you could do something like

```
ssh user@remote sh -c 'dothis ; dothat'
```

but you've got an `scp` in the middle.  I'd use an RSA or DSA key, but you said you don't want to do that (why?).

For the second question, the `ssh` and `scp` commands both return a status indicating whether they succeeded.  For example, this:

```
ssh user@remote /bin/false ; echo $?
```

should print 1, indicating failure.  (Change `$?` to `$status` if you're using csh or tcsh.)  Read the man pages (`man ssh`, `man scp`) and look for the "EXIT STATUS" section at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely don't want to work with keys (which I don't understand), there is a way to open a connection and subsequently use it.

You can work with the ssh options `ControlMaster` and `ControlPath`: use `ControlMaster=yes` to establish a connection first, asking for the password, and leaving a control socket on the place you told to do so with `ControlPath`. Subsequenty, tell your ssh commands to make use of this socket with `ControlMaster=no`.

```
echo "Creating control socket"
ssh $USERNAME@$HOSTNAME -o ControlMaster=yes,ControlPath=whereveryouwant -Nf
echo "Permission to Access to Remote Machine"
ssh $USERNAME@$HOSTNAME -o ControlMaster=no,ControlPath=whereveryouwant "pg_dump -f /dbexport.sql -t tb1 -t tb2 -t tb3 dbname"
echo "Permission to Access to Remote Machine to transfer data file"
scp -o ControlMaster=no,ControlPath=whereveryouwant $USERNAME@$HOSTNAME:/dbexport.sql /export/bin/
echo "Permission to delete temporary file on remote machine"
ssh $USERNAME@$HOSTNAME -o ControlMaster=no,ControlPath=whereveryouwant "rm /dbexport.sql"
echo "Creating Database..."
```

But here I am not quite sure how to get rid of this control connection, which might be a security risk, at the right time. Maybe you replace the `-Nf` with -f 'sleep 30m'`, depending on how long the complete process will last.

Another alternative could be, if there is no other output on remote stdout, to get the SQL dump directly via pipe, without using a temporary file.

```
ssh $USERNAME@$HOSTNAME "pg_dump -f - -t tb1 -t tb2 -t tb3 dbname"  > /export/bin/dbexport.sql
```

Short, tidy, with no potentially disturbing intermediate files. (But I am not sure about the `-f -`part - maybe there is another way to tell pg_dump to output its stuff to stdout.)

Answer (score 0):

Copy from remote server to local machine with out creating file, use pipe

> ssh -C {ssh.user}@{remote_host} \ 'PGPASSWORD={remote_dbpassword}
>   pg_dump -U{remote_dbuser} {remote_dbname} | bzip2 -c' \  | bunzip2 -dc
>   | PGPASSWORD={local_dbpassword} psql -U{local_dbuser} {local_dbname}